# Estimation of the tail of a weighted probability distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Let $\rho:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R_+$ be a density function with finite first moment, i.e.

$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}~ \rho(x)dx\quad = \quad 1,\quad\quad\quad  \int_{\mathbb R^d}~ |x|\rho(x)dx\quad < \quad +\infty.$$

For each $q=(q_1,\ldots, q_d)\in \mathbb Z^d$, let $V_q\subset \mathbb R^d$ be defined by $V_q:= \Pi_{i=1}^d~ \left[q_i, q_i+1\right)$. My question is that, **under what conditions on $\rho$**, one has an estimation on the tail given by

$$\sum_{q:~ |q|\ge n}~ |q| \rho(q) \lambda(V_q),\quad \quad \quad (\ast)$$

where $|q|:=\sum_{i=1}^d q_i$ and $\lambda(V_q)$ denotes the Lebesgue measures of $V_q$. Thanks a lot!

PS: Indeed, the objective is to estimate the following term:

$$\sum_{q\in\mathbb Z^d}\int_{V_q}~ \big(|x|\rho(x)-|q|\rho(q)\big)dx.$$

Clearly a necessary condition is to assume that $\rho$ is continuous. However, to ensure the asymptotic behaviour for large $|q|$, the estimation of $(\ast)$ is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by estimation on the tail? The tail of what? A random variable which has density $\rho$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo The goal is to estimate the Wasserstein distance between $\rho(x)dx$ and another probability distribution given by discretising $\rho(x)dx$. So it remains to estimate the term given in the PS.

Comment: The problem is that the set $\mathbb Z^d$  has Lebesgue measure zero, hence we can modify $\rho$ on this set and have no guarantee on the term involved in (*). Uniform continuity (if it is assumed to be a reasonable assumption) can help.